# Inner use instead of Outer.Inner?

Tags: java, static, package, inner-classes, outer-join

I have one confuse why use Inner instead of Outer.Inner,
my code here

```
package com.demo;

public class Outer{
static int data=20;
static class Inner{
    void msg(){
        System.out.println("data is ="+data);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Outer.Inner obj=new Outer.Inner();
    obj.msg();
} 
}
```

Can anyone tell me why use Outer.Inner ,why we are not use Inner ?

Comment: Is your question "why _doesn't_ this code use `Inner` instead of `Outer.Inner`," or "why _can't_ it?" If it's the former: I don't know; you wrote the code, right? If it's the latter: it can.

Comment: Please read about [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what are you trying to say @Okuma.Scott you  think  i am new user of stackoverflow .

Comment: Have you actually tried using just `Inner`? You might be surprised

Comment: That would be the assumption, yes. The help section is there for good reason. Everyone should read it, but particularly those who are new to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can anyone tell me why use Outer.Inner ,why we are not use Inner ?"

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Outer.Inner obj=new Outer.Inner();
    obj.msg();
}
```

here you can use `Inner` and I would recommend it.
If you are in other class `MyClass` than you must use the `Outer.Inner` and if the app will go bigger than the static inner classes will be extracted to separate Outer2 class. Usually is a bad idea to write 1x Outer which has 100k line and 500 static Inner class on it .

Comment: Wow nic answer i dont know about this

Comment: @thnaks 13 years ago I didn't know either. :)